# A continuous periodic function with period 1 has a point x which gives same value as x+π

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous periodic function of period 1. Show that there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0 + π) = f(x_0).$

This is visually pretty clear but I cannot think of a complete proof. What I thought was to take a function $g(x)=f(x+k)-f(x)$ where $k=π-3$ and need to show $g(x)$ takes positive values somewhere and negative values somewhere.
But the problem is at $x=0,\\ f(k)-f(0)$ is positive does not imply at $x=1-k, \\f(1)-f(1-k)=f(0)-f(-k)$ is negative. i.e. I cannot use the trick which we do for 1/2*period case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**.  Good start, but there is nothing special about taking $x=0$.  Instead, suppose that $f$ has a minimum when $x=a$ and consider
$$g(a)\quad\hbox{and}\quad g(a-\pi)\ ,$$
where $g(x)=f(x+\pi)-f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x + \pi) - f(x)$ is continuous, if it did not achieve the value zero on $[0,1]$ then one would have $f(x + \pi) - f(x) > \epsilon$ or $f(x + \pi) - f(x) < -\epsilon$ on $[0,1]$ for some positive $\epsilon$. Thus the integral of $f(x + \pi) - f(x)$ over $[0,1]$ would not be zero.

But the periodicity of $f(x)$ ensures that if you integrate $f(x + \pi) - f(x)$ over $[0,1]$, you get zero; the integral of $f(x + \pi)$ is just a rearrangement of the integral of $f(x)$. Thus $f(x + \pi) - f(x) = 0$ for some $x$.