# Questions regarding period of continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous fundtion such that $f(x+1)=f(x) \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Pick out the true statements from the following:

(A) $f$ is necessarily bounded above

(B) There exists a unique $x_0$ such that $f(x_0+\pi)=f(x_0)$

(C) There exists infinitely many $x_0$ such that $f(x_0+\pi)=f(x_0)$

(D) There exists NO $x_0$ such that $f(x_0+\pi)=f(x_0)$

---

I am a bit confused with options B, C, D.

(A) Is **TRUE** because $f$ is a periodic, continuous function hence it is bounded

(B, C, D) are **FALSE**. Because the period of the function $f$ is either $n$ or $1/n$ for some natural number $n$. Hence we cannot have $f(x_0+\pi)=f(x_0)$.

Comment: It is not true that B,C,D are false. In fact exactly one of C and D must be true. You can use continuity to determine which.

Comment: $f(x_0+\pi)=f(x_0)$ for some $x_0$ doesn't imply that $f$ has period $\pi$ (or a fraction of it). For example, let $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ and let $x_0=\frac74-\frac\pi2$. Then you can check $f$ is periodic with period 1 but $f(x_0)=f(x_0+\pi)$. See here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3iipojrvcw

Answer (score 1):

[A continuous periodic function with period 1 has a point x which gives same value as x+π](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206470/a-continuous-periodic-function-with-period-1-has-a-point-x-which-gives-same-valu?rq=1) shows that there is at least one $x_0$ with $f(x_0+\pi)=f(x_0)$. But then we can replace $x_0$ by $x_0+n$ for any integer $n$ so (C) is true. Of cousre, this proves that (B) and (D) are false.